# Using the attask api, how can update a task

Tags: api, attask

Using the Attask api, how can a I add an update through the rest api?  Updating the task looks like it will completely replace all updates as per the PUT documentation on nested objects, and doing a post on the /api/update doesn't seem to work :  here is what I have tried so far using Powershell for testing
$url = "https:///attask/api/update?sessionID=$($session.data.sessionID)&message=Test Message from api&refObjID=56e9b1d100741c6eb3cab7df95269ba7&objCode=UPDATE&updateObjCode=NOTE"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url  -Method "POST" 
Result is :
Invoke-RestMethod : {"error":{"class":"java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException","message":null}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Updates, post to notes instead - e.g.

```
$url = "https://lockton.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/note?sessionID=$($session.data.sessionID)&updates={noteText:'Test Message from api',objID:'56e9b1d100741c6eb3cab7df95269ba7',noteObjCode:'TASK'}"

$postResult = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method "POST"

$postResult
```